# google sheet IMPORTXML for web https://allurepack.com/

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to web scrap to get the price from a website
https://allurepack.com/

I tried using a google formula IMPORTXML with XPath //*[@id="ProductSection-product-template"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/span[1]/span
but it's not working

Comment: Can I ask you about your expected value?

Comment: i am trying to get the price

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `i am trying to get the price`, I cannot still understand your expected value. I apologize for this again.

Comment: I am trying to get the price for each item

Answer (score 0):

The link you have mentioned does not have any price in it.
but if we scrape one of the pages inside this website, like "https://allurepack.com/collections/holiday-jewelry-boxes", you can get the price easily with this code:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://allurepack.com/collections/holiday-jewelry-boxes","//*[@id='Collection']/div[2]/div[1]/form/div/div/div[1]/span")
```

Also make sure that you put quotations around id.
when you copy XPATH of an element, it put double quotations (") around id

```
//*[@id="Collection"]/div[2]/div[1]/form/div/div/div[1]/span
```

but google function also needs a double quotation around the xpath_query so you need to replace double quotations to single quotation like this:

**from:**

```
//*[@id="Collection"]/div[2]/div[1]/form/div/div/div[1]/span
```

**to:**

```
//*[@id='Collection']/div[2]/div[1]/form/div/div/div[1]/span
```

and you will get the result.

[you can see my screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amh8o.png)